# How do you use RegEx to retrieve information from HTML tags when the HTML format differs from case to case?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

So I am grabbing various pages from https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus for various words and then using RegEx to parse out the several contextual definitions of each word. I'm running into the problem that different words have varying ways the page is formatted, so I'm having trouble getting a single Regular Expression to cover all the possible cases. Here are two examples.

https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/15
and
https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/16

Both examples are using basically the same RegEx, but I have to swap the * and swap the Greedy/Lazy order for the two capture groups. The two different examples are using data from two different words. You'll notice that if you use the same RegEx on both words, in one case, the RegEx will match a huge chunk of the HTML as opposed to the one part.

These two examples are using the same two different test strings as the two examples above, but are using the same Regular Expression and you'll see how it pulls more than is necessary:

https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/17
and
https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/16

I'm unsure of how to further refine the Regular Expression to pull only the definition in all cases. There are a few other formats the website can make the words, but I'm only using two different formats for the sake of the question and examples. I can work whatever the solution for this is into the other formats later.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks a ton.

Comment: try this regular expression `<span class="dt ">\s+(.*?)\s*<\/span>|<span class="dt ">\s+(.+?)\s*<ul class="vis"><li><span class="t">` it seems to work on both the examples given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your [first regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/15) and now it working :

1. [advertising](https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/18)
2. [About](https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/19)

## Remarks

```
# uncalled for matching of opening of span.thes-list
# matching only on character in the second part of the regular expression
<span class="dt ">(.*?)<\/span> <span class="thes-list sim-list">|<span class="dt ">(.?)<ul class="vis"><li><span class="t">
```

---

## Updated version

```
# matches only the content of the span (first part)
# added \s as to remove whitespace characters
# added quantifier to the second part +? match as much as possible non greedy
<span class="dt ">\s+(.+?)\s*<\/span>|<span class="dt ">\s+(.+?)\s*<ul class="vis"><li><span class="t">
```

## second edit

```
# matches only the description
<span class="dt ">\s+([^<]+?)\s+<
```

Comment: This solution includes the word being used in a sentence. I do not want that. But if I change the </span> to a tag that comes before the example sentence, it still retrieves the later instance of the tag, causing it to return the whole unnecessary parts.

Edit: I guess I can just use this, then trim out the sentence with another RegEx as the haystack would be **significantly** smaller with less associations. Thanks a bunch! Got me there!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble getting a single Regular Expression to cover all the possible cases.

That's because it's not feasible to write a single regex to cover all the possible cases.

To parse HTML reliably, you need to use an HTML parser.  You haven't said what language you're using, but http://htmlparsing.com/ can give you some starting points.